# Get unique values from sql table where contained ID from row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
$get_all_brand_auto = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_product WHERE manufacturer_id='$mid'");
```

As a result, I get the id of certain manufacturers . After that I have to make a request to the oc_product_attribute table to get a unique value "text".

This is table *oc_product_attribute*:

[image]

I need to get unique values ​​of the column "text".
But `product_id` in row should be in the array, which I received earlier

Comment: You just need to write more code.

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve this. What did you try?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: don't you mean  "I get the id of certain **products**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by one nested query

```
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE product_id IN (SELECT id FROM oc_product WHERE manufacturer_id='$mid')
```

By the way, as always, I recommend you to do not use the mysql library. It's deprecated.

Try using mysqli. [It's easy to learn](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)